# Throwing a custom exception. I want to override the casting error message

Tags: python

```py
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age < 0:
            raise ValueError('negative age')
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f'{ve}')
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        break
```

I want to override the casting error message.
*invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cat'*
with the error "Not a valid number"

Comment: Use `except Exception:` instead of `except:`; the latter catches exceptions you almost certainly do not intend to catch (like `SystemExit`, for example).

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `except ValueError as ve:`, what do you think this means? Under what conditions will the code in that block run, and what will be the value of `ve` when that happens? What do you want to happen when those conditions are met? What happens if you try putting that code, inside that except block? I don't understand how there is any confusion or question here about what needs to be done; it seems like you already know everything that is relevant to the problem, and just need to think more.

Comment: Unless the question is "how do I tell whether the `ValueError` came from the `int` call or from my explicit `raise`? In which case obviously you can just *raise a different type of exception*, or else inspect the message. If the question really is "how do I inspect the message" then that is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question specifically asks about a custom error, I guess we should include that answer! You can inherit from any other exception class. In your case a specialization of ValueError seems appropriate. Just make sure it precedes ValueError in the exception list.

```
class NegativeValue(ValueError):
    pass

while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age < 0:
            raise NegativeValue
    except NegativeValue:
        print('negative age')
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Not a valid number")
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the error that you raise to `RuntimeError` like this:

```py
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age < 0:
            raise RuntimeError('negative age')
    except RuntimeError as ve:
        print(f'{ve}')
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f'Not a valid number')
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        break
```

Sample session:

```
How old are you? -5
negative age
How old are you? cat
Not a valid number
How old are you? 5
```

**Update:**

And the alternative where you define your own custom ValueError class with that error message:

```py
class NegativeException(ValueError):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('negative age')
        
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age < 0:
            raise NegativeException()
    except NegativeException as ve:
        print(f'{ve}')
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f'Not a valid number')
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        break
```

Same output as before.

Comment: Lots of things are `RuntimeError`s, though; I would define a custom subclass of `ValueError` to use instead.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, that can be done easily . . .

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ValueError` for two different things, making it difficult to print the error message you want. You could change the exception type raised when you detect an error. But why use an exception at all? Print the message at the point the error is detected and `continue` back to the top of the loop

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('How old are you? '))
        if age < 0:
            print('negative age')
            continue
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Not a valid number")
    except:
        print('Error')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Occam's Razor !   Well done!